# dataframe: how to groupBy/count then filter on count in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark 1.4.1

I encounter a situation where grouping by a dataframe, then counting and filtering on the 'count' column raises the exception below

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

case class Paf(x:Int)
val myData = Seq(Paf(2), Paf(1), Paf(2))
val df = sc.parallelize(myData, 2).toDF()
```

Then grouping and filtering:

```
df.groupBy("x").count()
  .filter("count >= 2")
  .show()
```

Throws an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.7] failure: ``('' expected but `>=' found count >= 2
```

**Solution:**

Renaming the column makes the problem vanish (as I suspect there is no conflict with the interpolated 'count' function'

```
df.groupBy("x").count()
  .withColumnRenamed("count", "n")
  .filter("n >= 2")
  .show()
```

So, is that a behavior to expect, a bug or is there a canonical way to go around?

thanks, alex

Answer (score 59):

When you pass a string to the `filter` function, the string is interpreted as SQL. Count is a SQL keyword and using `count` as a variable confuses the parser. This is a small bug (you can file a JIRA ticket if you want to).

You can easily avoid this by using a column expression instead of a String:

```
df.groupBy("x").count()
  .filter($"count" >= 2)
  .show()
```

Comment: Why does the filter expression not work if I change it to '==' ?

Comment: @sqlconsumer.net use '==='

Answer (score 32):

> So, is that a behavior to expect, a bug

Truth be told I am not sure. It looks like parser is interpreting `count` not as a column name but a function and expects following parentheses. Looks like a bug or at least a serious limitation of the parser.

> is there a canonical way to go around?

Some options have been already mentioned by [Herman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2919937/herman) and [mattinbits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5142537/mattinbits) so here more SQLish approach from me:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.count

df.groupBy("x").agg(count("*").alias("cnt")).where($"cnt"  > 2)
```

Comment: how can i show all columns instead of the column X and the CNT col?

Comment: @abu-shoeb You can use `agg(...)` with more than one expression. A common pattern is to use `min(name)` for all the other columns you'd like to show, giving the smallest value of the column in each group. You would have to list all columns explicitly.

Answer (score 12):

I think a solution is to put count in back ticks

```
.filter("`count` >= 2")
```

http://mail-archives.us.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201507.mbox/%3C8E43A71610EAA94A9171F8AFCC44E351B48EDF@fmsmsx124.amr.corp.intel.com%3E

Comment: solution fits for pyspark also.