# How to do count(*) within a spark dataframe groupBy

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My intention is to do the equivalent of the basic sql

```
select shipgrp, shipstatus, count(*) cnt 
from shipstatus group by shipgrp, shipstatus
```

The examples that I have seen for spark dataframes include rollups by other columns: e.g.

```
df.groupBy($"shipgrp", $"shipstatus").agg(sum($"quantity"))
```

But no other column  is  needed in my case shown above.  So what is the syntax and/or method call combination here?

*Update*  A reader has suggested this question were a duplicate of [dataframe: how to groupBy/count then filter on count in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119936/dataframe-how-to-groupby-count-then-filter-on-count-in-scala)  : but that one is about filtering by `count` : there is no filtering here.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can similarly do `count("*")` in spark `agg` function:

```
df.groupBy("shipgrp", "shipstatus").agg(count("*").as("cnt"))
```

---

```
val df = Seq(("a", 1), ("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("b", 3)).toDF("A", "B")

df.groupBy("A", "B").agg(count("*").as("cnt")).show
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|cnt|
+---+---+---+
|  b|  2|  1|
|  a|  1|  2|
|  b|  3|  1|
+---+---+---+
```